# can't connected LAN with static gateway router

Tags: router, gateway

I try to connect LAN with my college network with static gateway router. My LAN is 192.168.0.0/24 and my college network is 10.42.11.0/24. But client (192.168.0.3) only ping 
 router(10.42.11.243).
It's interfaces in my router

> auto lo
>
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> auto eth0
>
> iface eth0 inet static
>
> address 192.168.0.1
>
> netmask 255.255.255.0
>
> network 192.168.0.0
>
> up route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 gw 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
>
> auto eth1
>
> iface eth1 inet static
>
> address 10.42.11.243
>
> netmask 255.255.255.0
>
> network 10.42.11.0
>
> gateway 10.42.11.1
>
> dns-nameservers 172.16.30.7

and this interfaces in client

> auto lo
>   iface lo 
>   inet loopback
>
> auto eth0
>
> iface eth0 inet static
>
> address 192.168.0.3
>
> netmask 255.255.255.0
>
> network 192.168.0.0
>
> gateway 192.168.0.1

when I using traceroute from client :

> traceroute to 10.42.11.1 (10.42.11.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
>
> 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  0.248 ms  0.244 ms  0.235 ms
>
> 2  * * *
>
> 3  * * *
>
> 4  * * *
>
> 30 * * *

when I using route in router

> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>
> default         10.42.11.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
>
> 10.42.11.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
>
> 192.168.0.0     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
>
> 192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
>
> 192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0

Answer (score 0):

You must set on `router` traffic forwarding.

First allow fw on system with command

```
sudo sh -c “echo 1 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip forward’’
```

and do some `iptables` fw rules

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state -–state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

Edit 1

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

and not forget

```
sudo sh -c “echo 1 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip forward’’
```

Comment: when I try "sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state -–state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT", then "iptables v1.4.21: unknown option "state" Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.", and client stil can't connect, How I fix it's ?

Comment: have new `rules` in `Edit 1`

Comment: stil can't connect

Comment: You can ping `10.42.11.243` but can not ping `10.42.11.1`?

Comment: yes.. client can ping 10.42.11.243 but can't ping 10.42.11.1

Comment: Do `traceroute 10.42.11.1` from client and put output in question

Comment: please, give output from `route` command from router.

Comment: change default gateway on router to `10.42.11.1`. Command is `sudo route add default gw 10.42.11.1`

Comment: Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.42.11.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.42.11.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0

Comment: gateway in my router already 10.42.11.1